# Help me understand the physics of masks

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, everyday-life, flow

Reference: A. Konda *et al.*, "Aerosol Filtration Efficiency of Common Fabrics Used in Respiratory Cloth Masks", [*ACS Nano* **2020**, 14, 5, 6339–6347](https://doi.org/10.1021/acsnano.0c03252).

The paper linked above was about experimentally determining the efficiency of different cloth masks.
They say the pressure difference determines the breath-ability and comfortableness of a mask.

1. Masks filter out tiny particles. So can masks be considered as a barrier as it allows us to breathe easily?
2. If so, how is a pressure difference created when we wear a mask as mentioned in the paper?

Comment: https://youtu.be/eAdanPfQdCA

Answer (score 2):

1. The tiny particles (of micron size) that the mask filters out is still much bigger than the dimensions of the gas molecules (of nano meter size) that we breathe. So the mask's ability to filter particles such as microbes is not necessarily a barrier to breathing.
2. Pressure difference is created in the process of drawing a breath due to expansion of lungs. This holds whether or not you wear a mask.

Comment: So basically wearing a mask won't create an additional pressure difference?

Comment: @IhsanAhmedK There will be pressure drop across the mask. In other words, you have to breathe harder with the mask on, but it is not that you can't breathe. How much pressure difference occurs across the mask depends on the porosity of the mask.